# How does energy conversion during phase transition occur at a molecular level?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, phase-transition

I am frustrated by thinking about it

Whenever I ask someone why temperature does not change, the person says it is because the heat goes into changing the intermolecular forces, and not KE.

I WANT TO KNOW WHY

Why does heat not go into changing the KE at that time when melting starts? Why doesn't the temperature keep on rising and why doesn't the KE change like it would if I was just giving it normal heat.

(Let there be an object which requires 1000J to get to the melting point
If I supply it 50J of energy, the temperature rises and there is a partial conversion between PE and KE. If I give it the same after it has entered the melting phase, no temperature change and all go to PE. WHY? why doesn't the partial conversion happen when I supply it with less energy?)
Note: Please note that I know that bond are missing energy places
PLEASE HELP

Comment: Welcome. Please consider not using all caps for full sentences. Some consider it rude (as if you where shouting). Also remember that you can edit your post at any time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of two rules as applying for phase changes at equilibrium:

1. For different temperature ranges, there are certain phases that are stable; other phases are not stable. The stable phase is the one with the lowest [Gibbs free energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_free_energy):
   [image]
   You can verify that we transition from solid to liquid to gas with increasing temperature, as expected.
2. We can't change from one phase to another without adding or removing the so-called [latent heat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_heat).

From these two rules, we conclude that there must be a delay at the phase-change temperature as we add or remove the energy required to obtain the new phase. This is unavoidable. Once this is completed, we can start changing the temperature of the new phase.

Note that heating a material generally changes both potential and kinetic energy; it's only for the special case of the ideal gas that no potential energy exists, with all temperature changes affecting the kinetic energy only.

Comment: No but why is that the latent heat doesnt increase the KE

Comment: Because if the KE were to increase (for the solid at the solid–liquid phase transition, for example) then the temperature would have to increase, and we'd have a solid in the equilibrium liquid region, which violates rule no. 1 above. (Note that we're applying the classical approximation for high temperatures.) This is also discussed [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/560174/how-can-energy-be-absorbed-without-changing-the-temperature/560230).

Comment: Sir, i am asking that why does latent heat not go to increase temperature? Is it experimental like measuring the difference in KE between just melting and just melted molecules?